# Ethereum send transaction for only one account

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I have Ethereum account (@/Eth).
I use TestRPC and Truffle

```
0xb1c38c605b8468cea3fc51e204098659c666b8b9/41.86142259999994
0x7c6b249c8b721845df50d60c3a6eda75db36212a/41.86142259999994
0x2d8e958af078aba822a73d6bac8b1d116d5769fa/41.86142259999994
0x24c236cb31704b5a20c39ff165543ce9a058924a/41.86142259999994
```

I want transfert Ether from 1° account to the 2° account.
I try :

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0xb1c38c605b8468cea3fc51e204098659c666b8b9', to: '0x7c6b249c8b721845df50d60c3a6eda75db36212a', value: web3.toWei(3, "ether")})
```

But all account are debited :'( Why ?

```
0xb1c38c605b8468cea3fc51e204098659c666b8b9  38.86142259999992
0x7c6b249c8b721845df50d60c3a6eda75db36212a  38.86142259999992
0x2d8e958af078aba822a73d6bac8b1d116d5769fa  38.86142259999992
0x24c236cb31704b5a20c39ff165543ce9a058924a  38.86142259999992
```